# how to get the selected value from <oj-select-one>?

Tags: javascript, oracle-jet

i have a oj-select-one  componenet with the following def :

```
<oj-select-one id="select1" style="max-width:20em" 
                 options={{data3}}
                 value="{{data3.Id}}"
                 options-keys="{{optionKeys2}}" >
</oj-select-one>
```

and in the js file the optionkeys are

```
self.optionKeys2 = {value:"Id", label:"CourseName"};
```

i want to get the Id of the selected one and store that value 
in a var 
how to achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a new observable for that.

```
<oj-select-one id="select1" style="max-width:20em" 
             options={{data3}}
             value="{{selectedValue}}"
             options-keys="{{optionKeys2}}" >
</oj-select-one>
```

**JS**

```
self.selectedValue = ko.observable();
self.optionKeys2 = {value:"Id", label:"CourseName"};
```